# R DBI object types incompatible with dplyr?

Tags: r, database, dplyr

I was  trying to follow the code example below [from here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/meta-big-picture.html)

```
library(dplyr)

    con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), filename = ":memory:")
    mtcars_db <- copy_to(con, mtcars)
    
    mtcars_db %>%
      filter(cyl > 2) %>%
      select(mpg:hp) %>%
      head(10) %>%
      show_query()
    
    DBI::dbDisconnect(con)
```

Instead of the results on the website, I got the following error:

Error in storage.mode(x) <- "double": 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
Traceback:

> 1. mtcars_db %>% filter(cyl > 2) %>% select(mpg:hp) %>% head(10) %>%   .     show_query()
> 2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
> 3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
> 6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
> 7. function_list[i]
> 8. filter(., cyl > 2)

The DBI object seems to be loaded correctly, and prints :

```
# Source:   table<mtcars> [?? x 11]
# Database: sqlite 3.30.1 []
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# … with more rows
```

The error occurs even if just the first pipe is used :

```
mtcars_db %>%
          filter(cyl > 2)
```

Also, `is.data.frame(mtcars_db)` returns FALSE.

*Does anyone know what went wrong here?*

*Does the pipeline here only work for R dataframes?*

(This is with latest R 4.03 and tidyverse, under Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Please would you check the link? I don't see any of the code in question on the page you have linked to.

Comment: @Simon.S.A. Sure, the code is at `17.6 Customising evaluation with functions` on the page linked. It's the second code block.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when the example was written `copy_to` returned a connection to the database object. But now its return type has changed (or is different in the package version you have loaded).

If so, you need a new command to connect to the remote table. Try the following:

```r
# as per the question
library(dplyr)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), filename = ":memory:")
mtcars_db <- copy_to(con, mtcars)

# confirm is not a (remote) table
is.data.frame(mtcars_db)
# connect to the remote table
mtcars_db <- tbl(con, "mtcars")
# confirm now a (remote) table
is.data.frame(mtcars_db)
```

You might also want to use `class` and compare `class(mtcars)` against `class(mtcars_db)`.